# How to get Confusion Matrix or True/False Positive/Negative labels from Google VertexAI's aiplatform library?

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, classification, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to retrieve metrics and other model evaluations from Google Cloud's VertexAI via their python library, specifically, I'm having trouble accessing a confusion matrix for a text classification model. Or at least get the values of true positives/false positives/false positives/true negatives, so I can create a confusion matrix myself.

I've been able to extract log loss, precision, recall, f1, AUPRC and confidence thresholds via `.get_model_evaluation()` in aiplatform or `.GetModelEvaluationRequest()` in aiplatform_v1. I can also get the same set of metrics by level metrics by using corresponding evaluation slice methods.

However, I can't seem to find anywhere in their documentation how to generate either a confusion matrix or the values used in the evaluation to get the metrics returned above. In the Evaluation UI they list items by true/false pos/neg but I can't figure out a way to retrieve these. Also Confusion Matrix is listed in [their evaluation guides here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/evaluation/introduction#text) for text classification and in the ClassificationEvaluationMetrics schema yaml in GCS they link to in the guide, but I can't find it in the model evaluation object.  Is it possible to pull a confusion matrix and/or labels used in training/evaluation using python?